# Jquery to append text in textbox from other textboxes in the same Mvc view

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have 3 textboxes on a form in my mvc view, FirstName, LastName, UserName.  The UserName needs to be the FirstName + LastName.  I tried the following Jquery which will add the letters of the FirstName field to UserName on the FirstName.KeyUp event, but when I add letters from the LastName field to the UserName it overwrites the FirstName letters (actually I only need the 1st letter of the lastName).  What is the Jquery for this to "Append" letters and not overwrite?  Is KeyUp a good event for this -- maybe LostFocus or something?  Or should I use a function that returns a value with the return keyword?  What is the Jquery for that approach?

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {

    <fieldset>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FirstName)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FirstName)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FirstName)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LastName)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.LastName)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LastName)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserName)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.UserName)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UserName)
        </div>
    </fieldset>
}


<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function () {

        $("#FirstName").keyup(function () {            
            $("#UserName").val(this.value);
        });
        $("#LastName").keyup(function () {
            $("#UserName").val(this.value);
        });

    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read both the input values(*FirstName and LastName*) and append it to get the final value and still overwrite the UserName input value.

```
$(function(){

   $("#FirstName").keyup(function () {            
        $("#UserName").val($(this).val()+ $("#LastName").val());
   });

   $("#LastName").keyup(function () {
         $("#UserName").val( $("#FirstName").val()+$(this).val());
   });

});
```

If you want to add only the first letter of last name, you can do this

```
$(function(){

   $("#FirstName").keyup(function () {   
        var lastName = $("#LastName").val();
        if(lastName!=='')
        {
           lastName=lastName.charAt(0);               
        }
        $("#UserName").val($(this).val()+ lastName);
   });

   $("#LastName").keyup(function () {
        var lastName = $(this).val();
        if(lastName!=='')
        {
            lastName=lastName.charAt(0);               
        }
        $("#UserName").val( $("#FirstName").val()+lastName);
   });

});
```

[Here](http://jsbin.com/vupeximazi/edit?js,console,output) is a working jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0):

add space between Firstname and Lastname, then you need to write this code

```
$("#FirstName").keyup(function () {
        $("#UserName").val($(this).val() + ' ' + $("#LastName").val());
    });
    $("#LastName").keyup(function () {
        $("#UserName").val($("#FirstName").val() + ' ' + $(this).val());
    });
```